# Static Resource Error in Spring Boot When Accessing api/mypage via Postman"

Tags: spring-boot

I can access /signup without any issues, but I'm encountering a 'No Static Resource' error for other routes.

**mypageController**

```
import fairy.spring.fairy.config.utils.ApiResponseBuilder;
import fairy.spring.fairy.user.request.MypageRequest;
import fairy.spring.fairy.user.response.MypageResponse;
import fairy.spring.fairy.user.service.MypageService;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Operation;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.responses.ApiResponse;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.tags.Tag;
import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipal;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@Tag(name="mypage", description = "mypage api")
@RestController
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class MypageController {

    private final MypageService mypageService;

    @Operation(summary = "profile", description = "profile")
    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "201", description = "success")
    @GetMapping("/mypage")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getProfile(@RequestParam MypageRequest.MypageinfoRequestDTO mypageinfoRequestDTO, @AuthenticationPrincipal PrincipalUserDetails userDetails) {
        MypageResponse.MypageinfoResponseDTO mypageinfoResponseDTO = mypageService.updateprofile(mypageinfoRequestDTO);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(ApiResponseBuilder.success(mypageinfoResponseDTO));
    }
}
```

**mypageService**

```
package fairy.spring.fairy.user.service;


import fairy.spring.fairy.user.domain.MypageInfo;
import fairy.spring.fairy.user.domain.User;
import fairy.spring.fairy.user.repository.MypageRepository;
import fairy.spring.fairy.user.repository.UserRepository;
import fairy.spring.fairy.user.request.MypageRequest;
import fairy.spring.fairy.user.response.MypageResponse;
import jakarta.transaction.Transactional;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
public class MypageService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final MypageRepository mypageRepository;



    @Transactional
    public MypageResponse.MypageinfoResponseDTO updateprofile(MypageRequest.MypageinfoRequestDTO mypageinfoRequestDTO){
        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(mypageinfoRequestDTO.getEmail()).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("User not found."));
        MypageInfo mypageInfo = mypageRepository.findByEmail(mypageinfoRequestDTO.getEmail()).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("User not found."));

        return new MypageResponse.MypageinfoResponseDTO(user.getNickname(),mypageInfo.getPoint(),mypageInfo.getGrade());
    }
}
```

**usercontroller**

```
@Tag(name = "User", description = "user API")
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class UserController {
    private final UserService userService;

    @Operation(summary = "signup", description = "signup")
    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "success")
    @PostMapping("/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<?> signup(@RequestBody @Valid UserRequest.SignupRequestDTO requestDTO, Errors errors) {
        userService.signup(requestDTO);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(ApiResponseBuilder.successWithNoContent());
    }
```

**userservice**

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
public class UserService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final TokenProvider tokenProvider;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public UserResponse.LoginResponseWithTokenDTO login(UserRequest.LoginRequestDTO request) {
        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(request.getEmail())
                .orElseThrow(() -> new Exception400(null, "not match"));

        if (!passwordEncoder.matches(request.getPassword(), user.getPassword())) {
            throw new Exception400(null, "not match");
        }

        String token = tokenProvider.createToken(user.getEmail());

        UserResponse.LoginResponseDTO loginResponseDTO = new UserResponse.LoginResponseDTO(user.getEmail(), user.getNickname(),  user.getId());

        return new UserResponse.LoginResponseWithTokenDTO(loginResponseDTO, token);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void signup(UserRequest.SignupRequestDTO requestDTO) {
        requestDTO.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(requestDTO.getPassword()));
        userRepository.save(requestDTO.toEntity(RoleEnum.USER));
    }
}
```

**securityConfig**

```
@EnableMethodSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig   {
    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;  
    private final JWTAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;   JWTAuthenticationEntryPoint 


    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }



    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.addAllowedOriginPattern("*"); 
        configuration.addAllowedHeader("*"); 
        configuration.addAllowedMethod("*"); 
        configuration.addExposedHeader("Authorization"); 
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration); 
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)) 
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .cors(corsConfigurer -> corsConfigurer.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())) 
                .formLogin(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable) 
                .httpBasic(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable) 
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("/test/**").authenticated()
                        .anyRequest().permitAll())
                .headers((headers) -> headers
                        .addHeaderWriter(new XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter(
                                XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter.XFrameOptionsMode.SAMEORIGIN)))
                .exceptionHandling(exceptionHandling -> exceptionHandling
                        .authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint))
                .build();

    }


}
```

**application.yml**

```
server:
  servlet:
    encoding:
      charset: utf-8
      force: true
  port: 8080
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/user
    driver-class-name: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
    username: root
    password: 0000
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        format_sql: true
      default_batch_fetch_size: 100
    open-in-view: false
```

**error**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IykxR.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trmzt.png)

I've checked both my yml and security config files, and there are no restrictions or typos. I can't figure out why this is happening.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).